# Need to receive swipe events in non-key window

Tags: cocoa, macos, swipe-gesture

In my Cocoa app, I need to handle swipe gestures in a non-key window. Unfortunately, gesture events are only delivered to the key window. Making my window key is not an option.

Any workarounds anyone knows about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the note Francis.  I wasn't able to find a way to do this. Instead I just used the scrollview's scrollWheel: events and used my own algorithm to detect swipes. Not perfect but seems to work okay.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I've found is to have your window's view watch for mouseEntered: events, and call NSApp's activateIgnoringOtherApps: method. This is not standard behaviour, though.